# How to add/include js file into Magento theme

Tags: javascript, magento

I am modifying a Magento theme. And want to add a js file into the theme `/js` folder. I have added the following code:

`<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom-script.js</name></action>`

into the `/app/design/frontend/theme-name/default/layout/page.xml` and published the js file into `/skin/frontend/theme-name/default/js/`. But no luck. It is not showing on the page.

Answer (score 14):

Try adding the following to your layout `.xml` file within `<reference name="head">`

```
<action method="addJs">
    <script>js/custom-script.js</script>
</action>
```

Comment: Would you please tell us Where to add it ? Which file to open for it. Where to write it ? Do we need to create new file or existing file need to edit? What name to give to this file ?

Comment: You can add to your "layout.xml" file within "reference name='head'"

Comment: Please edit the question and answer the questions I raised , as the answer will be used by many newbies.Thanks

Comment: I removed the 'js/' part, because it seems my magento (1.9) installation gave a 404 when adding this.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to `include javascript in`theme`then put this code in`your module's layout.xml`under`default` tag.

```
<layout>  
 <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>custom-script.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

If you want to `include javascript for any particular controller` then put this code in `your module's layout.xml` like below

```
<layout>  
<yourpackage_yourmodule_yourcontroller_action translate="label" module="yourpackage_yourmodule">       
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>custom-script.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</yourpackage_yourmodule_yourcontroller_action>
</layout>
```

And put `custom-script.js` file under `yourMagentoDirectory/js` folder.

Comment: Not trying to point out the mistakes, but people may get confused as you say to include `css` when I believe what you mean is include `js` which is what the questions about :)

Great answer though. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Where to put the layout.xml file?

Comment: Put it app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout.
For more help go with this http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in,

**app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/default/template/page/html/header.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>js/custom-script.js"></script>
```

And put **custom-script.js** file in **js** folder on root.

**FYI** : Like this you can add any js/css file on phtml files

Comment: Would you please tell us Where to add it ? Which file to open for it. Where to write it ? Do we need to create new file or existing file need to edit? What name to give to this file ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Look at this app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/default/template/page/html/header.phtml . Edit this file

Answer (score 4):

You can add your custom JS file in your theme's `local.xml`, located in: **/app/design/frontend/{design package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <reference name="head">
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script_name.js</name></action>
       </reference>
    </default>
 </layout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this, i think this is the way to add our js/css files into the load.xml:

```
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Works on both js and css

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom-script.js</name></action>
```

to

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>skin/frontend/{Theme Package Name}/{Theme Name}/js/custom-script.js</name></action>
```

that should allow you to access theme specific javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution insert into local.xml file with reference name="head"

```html
<action method="addJs">
    <script>js/custom.js</script>
</action>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to implement custom code (a .js file), please follow these steps:

- From the Admin panel, go to Design > Themes Editor.
- Click Customize    under the theme you wish to add custom script to.
- Click Java Script    Editor in the left panel to manage JavaScript
  assets.
- Click Browse    Files, select the JavaScript file from your local
  drive, and then    click Upload Files.

Comment: Where is the "Themes Editor"? I can not locate the link.