# How to include custom js file with script in Magento ecommerce website ver 1.3.2.4

Tags: javascript, magento

Hello I am trying to figure out how to add a .js file to the main layout within Magneto I created my js file but can't seem to get it to load in the layout. Where do I need to include the `<script>` tag in the main layout? I am using Magento ver 1.3.2.4

Comment: I think this question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093139/how-to-add-include-js-file-into-magento-theme) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654822/adding-external-javascript-file-to-magento).

Comment: Magento 1.3.2.4? Time to update!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your .js file in page.xml file in your theme folder.

Put .js file in your theme package
skin/frontend/theme_package/current_theme/js/.js file

add below line under `<block type="page/html">` this block in page.xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/filename.js</name></action>
```