# Magento skin and js missing from url

Tags: skin

I have a site on magento, before it's working fine after yesterday night on words css and js not loading. full site and admin also messed up.

Actually css url like this. http://siteurl.com/skin/frontend/default/town/css/styles.css

but for me it's showing 
http://siteurl.com/frontend/default/town/css/stylenm.css

From above skin missing. likewise js also showing, please any one help me !!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please contact your host provider, they will help to solve this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any other suggestions

Comment: what you did?  what changes you made now?

Comment: I have reviewed page.xml and .htaccess also changed permission to  777

Comment: dont change into htaccess just rename that then check

Comment: can you pls tell me where script declaring in magento. in the head.phmtl seem to be some of them only displaying

Comment: pls refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093139/how-to-add-include-js-file-into-magento-theme) .sorry bro i know only opencart and server cpanel