# Activating tab using link of the another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to activate the tab when I click the link on the other page like:

when i click `www.wakeke.com#go-to-tab2` the page will go to `www.wakeke.com#go-to-tab2` and the tab 2 is activated.

here is my sample:

```
<div class="section group">

    <div class="col span_1_of_4">  <!-- tab 1 -->
    <a href="www.wakeke.com#business"><img src="http://wakeke.com/media/wysiwyg/call_center.png" alt="" /></a>
<h3>sample</h3>
<p>sample/p>
    </div>

    <div class="col span_1_of_4">  <!-- tab 2 -->
    <a href="www.wakeke.com#marketing"><img src="http://wakeke.com/media/wysiwyg/marketing.png" alt="" /></a>
<h3>sample</h3>
<p>sample/p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the tab code:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li  class="active"><a href="#business"  data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://wwww.wakeke/media/wysiwyg/call_center_thumb.png" alt="" />
          <div class="job-desc">
          <h4>sample</h4>
          <h5>sample</h5>
           </div>
          </a></li>

<li><a href="#marketing" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://www.wakeke/media/wysiwyg/business_dev_thumb.png" alt="" />
          <div class="job-desc">
 <h4>sample</h4>
          <h5>sample</h5>
           </div>
</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

here is the image sample:
When I click the image:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Oxf.png)
it will go to another page and the tab is activated
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSqcj.png)

Please help me. :)
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript `location.hash` and some usefull jQuery this way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash!=""){

        // Get the hash value and remove the # from it.
        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

        // In the nav-tabs,
        // find the right tab by targetting the `h4` which contains the word you used has a hash
        // and click it.
        $(".nav-tabs").find("li h4:constains('"+hash+"')").click();
    }
});
</script>
```

So now, since you provided only a sample,
**You will have to find** the right words to use as a hash for each tabs.
Be carefull about case sensitivity.

Use one words contained in the `h4` tag inside the `li` (the tab) that you want to be active.

This small script must be in the page where tabs are... Anywhere in the `<body>`.
It takes the `hash` from the URL and remove the `#` character.
Then it uses it to find a tab.
It may find more than one! Which will not do what you want.

I think it is a good starter for you to try.
I didn't test this code as I'm used to do before posting here... So I hope there is no mistake.
;)

If you do not already use it, you have to include the jQuery library in your `<head>` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
I just noticed that you are using the same `hash` in the anchor's `href`.
So here is a variant of the same thing that should avoid the possibility of clicking more than one tab.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash!=""){

        // Get the hash value keeping the #.
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        // In the nav-tabs,
        // find the right tab by targetting the `a` which has the same href as your hash
        // and click it.
        $(".nav-tabs").find("li a[href='"+hash+'"]").click();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: do I need to add id in my <h4>? like <h4 id="marketing">

Comment: No... I just made an edit that is answering this and that is simplier. ;)

Comment: Its not working, the tab has a content in it, like: <div class="content" id="marketing">some text</div> inside the tab.

so I need to show the content inside the tab #marketing

thank you for your response :0

Comment: But when you click on the tab (on the `<a href="#marketing"...>` which is the `<li>`... Does it show the desired text ? I assumed that yes and simulated this click.

Comment: sorry, BTW, I'm using magento page, i can't insert the script

Comment: Yes, you can insert a script in Magento. You have to make an external .js file. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26093207/2159528